# How to connect to internet seamlessly when running Linux VMs inside Oracle VM VirtualBox when running on a restricted network?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet-connection

I'm running the latest version of Oracle VM VirtualBox on my Windows 10-64 bit system, in which I'm having **Kali Linux** which I've installed for my learning purpose since I do not want to dual boot my laptop.

The challenge is, I'm connected to a restricted network. I'm able to use the browser through the virtual box environment, but running commands like;

```
> sudo apt update
```

the terminal goes

```
1% [Waiting for headers]
...
...
...
     Connection failed [IP: 221.161.139.107 80]
Ign:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb)
Fetched 1,500 kB in 10min 8s (2,468 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 221.161.139.107 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I appreciate if there is an alternative option to circumvent this scenario and have complete access to the internet.

Comment: The challenge is, I'm connected to a restricted network. ...  What is your restriction.   .... Posted now from my Kali machine as a VMware guest and sudo apt update works fine.

Comment: This is a "*I had this problem, too*" comment. It is most probably a problem with the servers.  I used to have a WSL kali distro, on which I had to wait a whole day before I was finally able to download the distributed packages.

Comment: @John, I'm in a college network, that is the only restriction. I've tried those commands from my home Wi-Fi and it works perfectly. But, on this network it doesn't.

Comment: And that happened on my own computer, which didn't had any network restrictions. *Maybe because we belong to the same area and hence get connected to same servers?*

Comment: Check with your College IT Dept.

Comment: You should try using a mobile hotspot, if you can. If the connection gets established, the problem must be with your college network...